# ¿Crear columna unique laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas mediante `ManyToOne` para relaciones las imágenes asociadas a un determinado coche.
La idea es tener una columna en la tabla `imagenes` que indique si la imagen es la principal o no. Creé una columna `booleana` para esta operación. El problema es que solo puede haber un registro que tenga `true` para un `coche_id`.

**Es decir, solo puede haber una imagen principal para un coche**

Probé creando la columna y utilizando la propiedad `unique` pero no puedo tener más de dos registros con valor `false`. La pregunta entonces es, ¿cómo puedo hacer que solo haya un valor true en una columna para un mismo id?

Adjunto código de la migración:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('imagenes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('isMain')->default(false)->unique();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('imagenes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropUnique('imagenes_isMain_unique');
        });
    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para un mismo coche quiero que puedan haber muchas imágenes cuyo valor `isMain` sea `0` pero solo un registro pueda tener `1`

Comment: No entiendo, no es solo poner 1 al principal y 0 a los otros?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que no se pueda introducir más imagenes con valor 1 para el mismo coche @JuanRivera , no sé si me explico...

Comment: mmm lo que quieres entonces es que la propia base de datos te diga: Solo puede existir un valor 1 en este campo? Para que los otros sean 0, cosa que ya existe 1 y quieres poner otro 1 ya no te lo permita como dije antes no?

Comment: Sí @JuanRivera, eso es lo que quiero hacer. Pero creo que tienes razón con comprobar la existencia del valor cuando vaya a introducir el valor en el formulario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nivel de integridad relacional lo ideal, pienso, sería poder tener [índices parciales como en PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-partial.html), pero MySQL no ofrece tal cosa. Sin embargo puedes aprovecharte de una característica de los índices únicos que es [no tomar en cuenta, para la unicidad, los valores nulos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-unique):

```
A UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.
```

Para esto el índice único debe ser sobre la combinación de (coche_id, isMain)

```
   $table->unique(['coche_id', 'isMain'], 'main_picture_unique');
```

Y tu columna `isMain` debe representar los falsos con NULL en vez de ceros.

Esta solución preserva la unicidad a nivel relacional por lo tanto es más robusta, pero a simple vista no será inmediato para otro desarrollador su propósito ni efecto, a menos que se deje bien documentada en el mismo código y no en un README perdido.

Otra solución que me parece más coherente y menos rebuscada es que el post sepa cuál es su imagen principal mediante un campo `main_image` que tiene una relación `hasOne` con las imágenes. Esto requiere refactorizar, pero no es tan malo si pensamos que hoy estás más bien bloqueado y con el feature inconcluso, y que ahorrarte índices únicos compuestos es ahorrarse dolores de cabeza en el futuro.